# teechart; how to setup Tool cursor snap and assigned Series

Tags: visual-studio, activex, teechart

How do you assigned a Series to the Tool Cursor Snap via programming?

I am trying to assign a first Series to Tool cursor snap via programming. I read the document that is state:

ICurstorTool
Property Snap: WordBool;
Type Library
TeeChartx
Description
Set Snap property to True to align the TCursorTool with the nearest series point.
Snap has no effect unless a series is assigned to the Series property.

My code:

```
m_lCursor1 = pToolList->Add((tchartNS::EToolClass)tcCursor);
tchartNS::IToolsPtr pToolsPtr(pToolList->GetItems(m_lCursor1));
m_pCursor = pToolsPtr->GetasTeeCursor();

m_pCursor->PutStyle((tchartNS::ECursorToolStyle)cssVertical);
m_pCursor->GetPen()->PutEndStyle((tchartNS::EPenEndStyle)esFlat);
m_pCursor->GetPen()->PutColor(RGB(0,120,0));            
m_pCursor->PutSnap(VARIANT_TRUE);
m_pCursor->Series = 0;             <<<<<<<<< Doesn't assign to Series0?
```

Comment: Hello user3280398, 
Seems the CursorTool snap propierty, works in latest TeechartActivex Pro 2015 without problems. I would suggest you test our trial version. You can get it form our download page. Here's the link: http://steema.com/evaluation
Thanks in advance,
regards.

Comment: Hello Sandra, The current version of Teechart ActiveX that I have the ICursorTool class and PutSeries( _variant_t ) API. The help file doesn't have an example to setup _variant_t parameters that is needed for ICursorTool->PutSeries( _variant_t ). At this time, we cannot updated the ActiveX because software certification by customers. Can you ask your developer to show me how to setup the _variant_t parameter for Series0. I would like to have the cursor snap to series0. Thank you for answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

> Can you ask your developer to show me how to setup the _variant_t
>   parameter for Series0. I would like to have the cursor snap to
>   series0.

Yes :). To assign the Series to a TeeCursorTool you should create a Variant variable. Then you should assign the Series in that. The code below shows how you can do it:

```
...
    //AssignSeries
    VARIANT SourceSeries;
    SourceSeries.vt = VT_DISPATCH;
    SourceSeries.pdispVal = m_ctrlChart.Series(0);
    m_ctrlChart.GetTools().GetItems(0).GetAsTeeCursor().SetSeries(SourceSeries);
```

Could you tell us if the code works in your end?

Comment: Hi, I did take this code and tried to execute it. I got exception "E_UNEXPECTED Catastrophic failure." for calling PutSeries(.....).

Comment: Hello!
We can't reproduce the problem you are experiencing here.  Could you please send us the project are you using? You can attach the project in our upload page. Here's the link: http://www.steema.net/upload/ . Also, if you prefer you can send an email to "sales at steema dot com" or "info at steema dot com" addressed to Sandra Pazos.